# AngularJS component/controller JavaScript files loads in series not parallel (specific to Chrome compiled for AMD)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, asynchronous, amd-processor

I am looking at performance improvements for first-load (non-cached) for a Flask/AngularJS delivered webpage (transition to Angular and better route design is in the works, looking for a temporary fix).

This page includes a ton (250+) of JavaScript files on load. We are noticing on that these files are being loaded in series vs in parallel on some machines and not others.

The issue seems to be specific to the Chrome on an AMD machine (v 96.0.4664.93). We are not seeing this on Firefox on the same machine or on Chrome on Intel machines. This difference causes an increase in load time of nearly 15 seconds.

Question is can we force the problematic browser to download these in parallel to the cache? We attempted to use the async attribute in the script tag, but it causes some files to be loaded out of order.

Comment: Maybe it would be worth bundling and minifying your files? I suspect these 250+ files aren't minified, and contain comments? 250+ files is really, _really_ a big number. You can't let your user's browser make 250+ HTTP requests, just to load your JS code. You need to bundle that.

Comment: `can we force the problematic browser` --> It's funny, you don't even seem to have considered that the problem was not the browser, but having an application scattered in 250+ files...

Comment: @JeremyThille Our code design is definitely the number 1 issue lol. I only used the term problematic because it seems to be affected in only one build of chrome. This is a legacy platform that we are supporting. Our plans to transition to a better design structure, including files when necessary specific to the route, and using a newer framework are in the works. Just looking for a temporary solution in the interim.

Comment: Makes sense. As I said, simply minify and bundle your files, for instance with [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/). Minify with [Gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) and bundle with [Gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat). It will produce one minified JS file instead of 250+ unminified ones with comments. That will already be a HUGE perf improvement, and is a nice patch while making a transition to a new architecture.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.